# Invoke Child Action on clicking a Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to call my Child action on clicking any link. Basically what I know is Child Actions are called with @Html.Action() method. But this methods gets invoke automatically inside our view. I am trying to use @Html.ActionLink() but this is not working. Is there any way that we can call our Child actions on clicking any link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AJAX link which will invoke the action and inject the partial result into the DOM. For example assuming you have the following action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return PartialResult();
}
```

you could write an action link and a div to hold the results:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "someaction", "somecontroller", null, new { id = "mylink" })
<div id="result"></div>
```

and then in a separate javascript file AJAXify this link:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#result').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Darin. Thanks for the help. But can you suggest some way in which I dont have to deal with Ajax. Because if I want to use Ajax then I probably might now use Child actions in my case.

Comment: @Jash, if you don't want to use AJAX when a link is clicked a full postback to the server will be performed. So inside the resulting view you could include the child action using Html.Action.